# Making a template based on an internal class

Tags: c++, oop, templates, inheritance

I am trying to make a class that is templated on one of its internally defined classes.

I thought that by forward declaring the relevant classes, I'd be okay.
But I keep getting compile-time errors like:

```
use of undefined type QueryGetCustomer
Reply uses undefined class QueryGetCustomer
```

Is there a way I can template `QueryGetCustomer` on class `Reply`, when class `Reply` is internal to `QueryCustomer`, as shown in this code?

```
class QueryGetCustomer;
class QueryGetCustomer::Reply; // error: use of undefined type QueryGetCustomer
                               // error: Reply uses undefined class QueryGetCustomer

class QueryGetCustomer :
   public BaseQuery<QueryGetCustomer::Reply>
{
public:
    class Reply { [....] };
};
```

P.S.  I have this templating structure working when class `Reply` is external (global) to the `QueryGetCustomer` class.

However, the `Reply` only really makes sense within the Query, so I'd really like to have it as an internal class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whole thing fails on trying to forward declare inner class.

You cannot forward declare inner type of class. That's it.